# Issues with WinPython after installing Docking Station Driver

Tags: python, driver, pyqt5, spyder

I am using Spyder through the WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5 distribution on my Windows 7 Laptop. To add a third screen to my Laptop I started using a USB 3.0 Docking Station. After Installing the drivers Spyder won't launch, neither will the WinPython Control Panel.

These are the drivers I installed:

DisplayLink Graphics Driver Version: 8.0.762.0

DisplayLink Ethernet Driver Version: 8.0.403.0

DisplayLink Audio Driver Version:    8.0.745.0

Uninstalling the drivers fixes the problem, but my question is if this is a known issue and if there is a way to use both Spyder and the Docking Station.

So far I have tried updating PyQt5, which had no effect.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Spyder will launch but will not work on the second and third screens. However when I move the window back into my laptop screen it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a solution to the problem, but it's how I am able to use Spyder again.

I downloaded and installed the latest Anaconda (Version 5.0.1) distribution. I am able to launch Spyder, which is included in that distribution, even with the docking station drivers still installed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine. The issue was the way DisplayLink and Microsoft work together. Microsoft has admitted to there being an issue with the Windows kernel mode graphics driver. This is only an issue for machines with two+ graphics cards and the use of DisplayLink. DisplayLink uses the graphics card that Windows registers in the kernel, which by default is the primary monitor. On my HP laptop, the Intel graphics card is only used on the laptop screen (the primary) and is registered in the kernel, the NVIDIA card I have is used for all external screens, not registered. When you move an application, such as Spyder/Python, to the external monitors, the program's graphics will not work properly as you will be using DisplayLink, which is set to use the Intel graphics card, but you are now on the NVIDIA card. This does not happen to all apps, just those that rely heavily on the DisplayLink driver, these programs typically include GPU heavy programs such as emulators. To fix this, I disabled the Intel Graphics card, forcing the laptop to use the NVIDIA card and for the NVIDIA card to register with the kernel. This is not an ideal solution, but until Microsoft finds a fix for this, we are forced to use this method.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed you issue! My is different to yours. My laptop only has one graphics card. And Spyder, installed through the WinPython distribution won't even launch. But I installed Anaconda, which also includes Spyder and with that it is working again.